My Approved Domain Is Not Working, Do I Need To Upgrade API Key?
Which docs would help with updating this? My app is using version": "6.8.3", deployed using REACT/Vercel... I'm also using visual studio code. Do I need to fetch a new API key? Currently using this one:  apiKey={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TINYMCE_KEY}
I tried to re-register the page domain and it looks like it was approved.
